# How to delete a range of values from a list and make the aforementioned subtracted range unavailable in a new list?

Tags: python, list, range, list-comprehension

I am wondering if it is possible to create a function to subtract a range of values from a list, and a new list be created in which the aforementioned range of values that was subtracted are now "unavailable". I will put my thinking below in iterations:

I have my initial list with values that range from 0 to 1000 by 1, so `lista = [*range(0,1001)]`.

**First iteration**

```
lista = [*range(0,1001)]
```

**Second iteration**

I subtract `[*range(450,602)]` from `lista`

*New ranges available 301 to 449 and 602 to 1000*

**Third iteration**

I subtract `[*range(700,800)]` from `lista`

*New ranges available: 301 to 449, 602 to 699, 801 to 1000*

So now if I wanted to subtract `[*range(430,501)]` from `lista` it would be "unavailable" because it overlaps a now "unavailable" range. However, `[*range(650,671)]` would be "available".

I know I can subtract a range of values using `set()` with something like, `list(set(lista)-set(newRange))`), however, my issue is how identify the previous subtracted ranges, or values within those subtracted ranges, as being "unavailable".

Comment: Before subtracting from the list, check that all the elements being subtracted are in the list.

Comment: If these are unique values in the list, consider using sets instead.

Comment: Can you explain what is going on in the 3rd iteration?  How does subtracting the same range again cut out the values from 700-800?

Comment: @Tom Apologies, I accidentally typed in the same range to be subtracted for the second and third iterations in my question, I fixed it now, it should have been `[*range(700,800)]`

Comment: What’s this going to be used for?

Comment: @Ry- I want to test simulations where something is unavailable at a certain time, so I thought it would be good to start with a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, how about this?

```
def range_subtraction(ls, low, hi):
    if len(set(range(low, hi)) - set(ls)):
        raise Exception('Unavailable range.')
    else:
        return list(set(ls) - set(range(low,hi)))
```

If there are `range` values outside the input, then throw an error.  Otherwise, do the set subtraction you mentioned.

So if you do the following, `a` works but `b` throws the `Exception`:

```
a = range_subtraction(lista, 450, 602)
b = range_subtraction(a, 430, 501)
```